# Deleting any node in a single linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a Java linked list. The program is giving me a null pointer whenever I try to delete the next to last node.

Here are the attributes:

```
public class Nodo {
  int num;
  boolean used;
  Nodo next;        
}
```

And this is the method so far:

```
    public int delete(int val) { // deletes, (1:deleted, 0:not found, -1:empty
                                // list)
    int deleted = 0;
    if (n.used) {
        if (n.next == null) {
            if (n.num == val) {
                n.used = false;
                deleted = 1;
            }
        } else {
            Nodo it = n;
            Nodo itAnt = null;
            while (it.next != null) {
                if (it.num == val) {
                    it.num = it.next.num;
                    it.next = it.next.next;
                    deleted = 1;
                }
                itAnt = it;
                it = it.next;
            }
            if (it.num == val) {
                itAnt.next = null;
                deleted = 1;
            }
        }

    } else {
        deleted = -1;
        System.out.println("Empty list");
    }
    return deleted;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Who is `n` ? Which line throws an NPE ? Need some more context.

Comment: You're getting this exception at `itAnt.next = null`? This could happen if the loop `while (it.next != null)` was skipped. I guess you could initialize `itAnt` with `n` instead of null: `Nodo itAnt = n;`. This won't change the behaviour of your loop, but may fix your problem.

Comment: @Dici n is a node, the method is being called from a class that contains the first node, n.

Comment: @Tom Just tried it, won't budge. But thanks mate

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't look like a classic implementation of a linked list. You don't need any boolean `used`. You over-complicated that all.

Comment: Well .. where exactly occurs the NPE?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and indicate which line causes the NullPointerException.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Of course this code will throw an exception.
Here is the scenario:

There is a possibility that `it` will be the second to last node in the list and `it.num` will be equal to `val`.
Now, after the first iteration this while loop will have the following values:

```
while (it.next != null) {
    if (it.num == val) {
        it.num = it.next.num;
        it.next = it.next.next;  
        // "it.next" will be null. because "it" was one to last in the list.
        deleted = 1;
    }
    itAnt = it;    // This is the last item in the list
    it = it.next; // Here "it" will be null, because "it.next" is null
}
```

When it is time for the second iteration, `it.next` will throw a NullPointerException, because `it` was null already.

It is also worth mentioning that you don't need this line: `Nodo it = n;` because it is an object reference and both `n` and `it` are pointing at the same object. So whatever you do on `it`, is directly effecting the `n`.